# Byte vector to hex stringstream DWORD aligned

Tags: c++, vector, hex, stringstream

I want to convert my bytes stored in a `std::vector<unsigned char>` to a stringstream DWORD (4 bytes) aligned.

**Example:**

content of byte vector: 0x12 0x00 0x1B 0xAC 0x15 0xDF (6 Bytes)

```
std::stringstream stream;
//stream << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(8) ???
```

stream should look like: 12001BAC 000015DF

Is there an easy way with std::copy or how to implement this?

Comment: A little more details, please.  What does "???" stand for?

Comment: @JesseChisholm this line was just an idea from my side (its commented)!

Answer (score 0):

Is it that you don't want a loop?

```
for(int i=0; i < bytevector.size(); ++i)
{
    if ((0 != i) && (0 == (i%4)))
        stream << " ";
    stream << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << byteVector[i];
}
```

Comment: I think the `std::hex` and `std::setfill` can be lifted out of the loop, those change permanent state.